# How to exclude Character and have just numeric in R data

Tags: character, numeric

I should make a regression analysis about the relationship between income and authoritarianism. I have a database with 6k samples and in some of them I have characters instead of numerics. How can I quickly exclude characters instead of numerics?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have some range in your case and you cannot use directly. you should choose some categorical variables for those ranges. For example, replace the `ranges < 3000` by `1`, `3000<ranges<4999` by `2` and so on. Also, I found that your dataset has some missing values and for them, you have two options:

1) you can remove those rows

2) you can replace them by the mean of non-missing values.